# Do firestore transaction restart if new document is created in that reading collection

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

Let's say we have 10 tickets/slots from t1 to t10 as ticketIds, whenever a ticket is booked, a new document is created, and store the ticketId in the collection. And let's say we have created t1,t2, and t3 documents in the collection.

Now the user wants to update his ticket, and to update the t3 to t6 ticket, using **transaction** I have to read all available documents from the collection and check whether 't6' exist in the collection if not then update the document with t6 id.

Now my question is will transaction restart if someone else create t6 document during this transaction, since this document was not retrieved during read operation as it was not created at that point of time.

Note: I am using firebase function in node.js (admin sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transaction on Firestore uses a compare-and-set approach to consistency. So:

1. If your code tries to read document `t6` through the transaction, the Firestore SDK keeps track of whether that document existed or not.
2. If you then write the document `t6`, the Firestore SDK includes the original state of `t6` and its update in the payload it sends to the database server.
3. If the state of `t6` that you got in step 1 no longer matches the actual database contents, the write is rejected by the server and the SDK retries the transaction.

So, yes the transaction will restart if somebody else created/updated `t6` between steps 1 and 3.

Comment: Thanks i getting result as you said.
Just to be clear, please note: I am not doing document read, it's actually query read (since i have to check all documents of collection) [ collectionRef.where('ticketId','==','t6') ].
And when i hover over t.get() function under transaction it show "Retrieves a query result. Holds a pessimistic lock on all returned documents", but since t6 want not retrieved during this event, i am confuse it sould not restart as per this statement.